# Differentiation of Inequalities

Tags: derivatives, inequality

I have a question related to differentiating inequalities. I have the following inequality.
$$ f(r) \leq f(r) \frac{\alpha r^2}{(f'(r))^2} \leq \beta (r^2 - a^2), \qquad for \ \ r > a $$
$f$ is a monotone increasing function, and $\alpha > 0$. I want to know if it is correct that after diferentiate the expression I obtain
$$ f'(r) \leq \frac{d}{d r} \left( f(r) \frac{\alpha r^2}{\left(f'(r)\right)^2} \right)  \leq 2 \beta r,$$
or if there exist any condition under which the last inequality is true.

Comment: In general differentiation does not preserve the inequality (integration does).

Comment: @peek-a-boo why?

Comment: compare $e^{-x}$ vs $-e^x$ which function is larger than which? How are the derivatives related?

Comment: @peek well! But any intuitive or geometric understanding or source...any?

Comment: @Cooperation well, sketch the functions I proposed, and their derivatives. The point is that if we start with a positive vs negative function we obviously know which is larger. But the thing is just because is a function is positive/negative, this DOES NOT place any restrictions on the slope (i.e the derivative) hence there is no reason at all for the derivatives to obey the same inequality as the original function.

Comment: @peek thanks it helped a lot?

Comment: @peek-a-boo now I see it. There is perhaps no extra condition for the inequality to be preserved after differentiating the expression?